# Android file upload using ftp

Tags: android, file-upload, server, synchronization

Android file upload not working and not showing any error or any exception.

I want to add up some thing like check the internet connection when it is working only then it tries to upload the file and also want to add up one more thing that it makes a sync between server and application that this code will be called automatically after regular interval of time when the internet connection is working.

I have tried many jar files to upload the file and make an ftp connection but nothing works. jar file link http://www.jibble.org/files/simpleftp.jar

```
import org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP;

File file = new File("/sdcard/CreativeDroid/test.txt");
```

this way I am calling MyAsyncTask class to upload a txt file

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(file.toString());

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Double> {

    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


            SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

            // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
            ftp.connect("www.creativetabs.co", 21, "username", "password");

            // Set binary mode.
            ftp.bin();

            // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
            //ftp.cwd("web");

            // Upload some files.
            ftp.stor(new File(params[0]));

            // Quit from the FTP server.
            ftp.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", e.toString());
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using ftp4j:

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

I have been using this since 3 years and it works flawless.

```
private int uploadFile() throws Exception {
    long fileSize = 0;
    boolean supported = ftp.isResumeSupported();
    String fileName = getFileName(file_path);
    String server_path = data.getServer_folder() + fileName;
    try {
        fileSize = ftp.fileSize(server_path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileSize = 0;
    }
    if (fileSize == 0) {
        ftp.upload(new java.io.File(file_path), new FTPDataTransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void transferred(int arg0) {
                uploaded = uploaded + arg0;
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "uploaded: " + uploaded);
            }

            @Override
            public void started() {
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "uplaod started");
            }

            @Override
            public void failed() {
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "upload failed");
                disconnectFTP();
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.FAILED;
            }

            @Override
            public void completed() {
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.SUCCESSFULLY_UPLOADED;
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "upload completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void aborted() {
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.ABORTED;
                disconnectFTP();
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "upload aborted");
            }
        });
    } else if (supported) { // resume file upload
        ftp.upload(new java.io.File(file_path), fileSize, new FTPDataTransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void transferred(int arg0) {
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "Resume data transfered: " + arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void started() {
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "Resume started");
            }

            @Override
            public void failed() {
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.FAILED;
                disconnectFTP();
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "Resume failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void completed() {
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.SUCCESSFULLY_UPLOADED;
            }

            @Override
            public void aborted() {
                outputCode = FTPOutputCodes.ABORTED;
                disconnectFTP();
                Utilities.showDLog(Tag, "resume aborted");
            }
        });
    }
    return outputCode;
}


protected void disconnectFTP() {
    try {
        ftp.disconnect(true);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [link]http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/manual.php#14
I tried this link but it still not working for me

Comment: Could you please copy your logCat details here.

Comment: 03-20 09:38:39.970  19584-19626/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
----------
03-20 09:38:45.069  19584-19599/com.parse.starter I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 182507(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(449KB) LOS objects, 27% free, 15MB/21MB, paused 8.476ms total 83.401ms
----------
03-20 09:38:45.909  19584-19599/com.parse.starter I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 124769(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 19.819ms total 104.856ms
----------